# Android if statement doesnt work on setOnClickListener

Tags: if-statement, android-intent, switch-statement

I have create a walkthrough android studio screen of 3 slides and I need that when I push the button mNextBtn, at the third slide, it change to another Java class. As you can see in the code below I've used an if statement but it doesn't work because when I run and I push the mButtonBtn button the app stop, how can I fix it?

```
public class Portada extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager mSlideViewPager;
private LinearLayout mDotLayout;

private TextView[] mDots;

private SliderAdapter sliderAdapter;

private Button mNextBtn;
private Button mBackBtn;

private int mCurrentpage;

 int mLogin;


public void onLogin (){
    if (mDots.length == 3){
        Intent intent= new Intent(Portada.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else
    {
        mSlideViewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentpage + 1);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_portada);

    mSlideViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.slideViewPager);
    mDotLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dotsLayout);

    mNextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
    mBackBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevBtn);

    sliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(this);

    mSlideViewPager.setAdapter(sliderAdapter);

    addDotsIndicator(0);
    mSlideViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewListerer);


    mNextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mDots.length == 3){
                Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else
            {
                mSlideViewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentpage + 1);
            }
        }
    });


    mBackBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSlideViewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentpage - 1);
        }
    });

}

public void addDotsIndicator(int position) {
    mDots = new TextView[3];
    mDotLayout.removeAllViews();

    for(int i = 0; i < mDots.length; i++ ){

        mDots[i] = new TextView(this);
        mDots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        mDots[i].setTextSize(50);
        mDots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTransparentWhite));

        mDotLayout.addView(mDots[i]);

    }

    if (mDots.length > 0){
        mDots[position].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
    }
}

ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewListerer = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

    }



    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int i) {

        addDotsIndicator(i);

        mCurrentpage = i;
        if (i == 0){
            mNextBtn.setEnabled(true);
            mBackBtn.setEnabled(false);
            mBackBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mNextBtn.setText("NEXT");
            mBackBtn.setText("");
        }else if(i == mDots.length - 1) {
            mNextBtn.setEnabled(true);
            mBackBtn.setEnabled(true);
            mBackBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mNextBtn.setText("FINISH");
            mBackBtn.setText("BACK");
        }else {
            mNextBtn.setEnabled(true);
            mBackBtn.setEnabled(true);
            mBackBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mNextBtn.setText("NEXT");
            mBackBtn.setText("BACK");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

    }
};
```

}

`

Comment: Where is `mDots` defined?

Comment: It is define as a textview [ ], I didn't put that part of the code because its fine, the trouble is in this part.

Comment: I'm seeing you change some current item, but it isn't clear when `mDots` would have a length of 3, causing the activity to change.

Comment: I've edited it so you can see now the whole code

Comment: post the stacktrace

Comment: sorry, what is the stacktrace?